# Turn off CA SiteMinder for the one site

Tags: iis, single-sign-on, siteminder

I need to use Shibboleth SP for the one of the sites on IIS 8.5 which was under the CA SiteMinder agent previously(v.12.52.100.499). I've removed SiteMinder module as well as handler for this site. But I'm still redirecting to the SiteMinder SSO page. I've checked the application web.config file, applicationhost.config and didn't find any SM parameters. How can I turn off the SiteMinder agent for the one site?

Comment: Enable FRT on 30x redirection responses, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis and then you should observe the culprit.

Comment: Are you using 301 permanent redirection? If so, Please remember to clean browser cache because the cache will keep redirecting to original SSO page for a period of time. If it has nothing to do with Browser cache. Please check your Failed request tracing log. If the redirection is caused by a handler. you will be able to find it. If the redirection come from asp.net pipeline, then please check your code.

Comment: Check the shibboleth2.xml file [<RequestMapper>](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SP3/RequestMap) elements to see if the host/path is protected?

Comment: I see 302 status for the main reqiuest. Have turned on FRT and there is an redirection by CASiteminderModule in the log file. Also I can see a redirection by Shibboleth module at the end of the log file. I'm confused as for this site there is no CASiteminder module is configured. Also I've checked web.config for this site to double check that CASiteMinder module is switched off. As an addition I've checked IIS server level modules. There is no CASiteMinder module overthere. Seems like once CASiteminder installed on IIS it handles all the requests.

Comment: The shibboleth2.xml is properly configured, I have <site name> in the <host> section and proper site ID.